# Multiple GetElementByID doesn't work, how do I loop Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I have multiple `getElementById` that are pulling in data from Google Sheets based on column titles. When I have just one `getElementById` it works perfectly but as soon as I add a second it doesn't. I've been told I need to Loop them but don't know how just yet. I would really appreciate it if you could help me loop them.

```js
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
      callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

httpGetAsync('https://spreadsheet.glitch.me/? 
key = 1 JBbAHH1DFtO1r56lr94lUqd8H7qPcHncJskcPq0r96o ', function(response){
var json = JSON.parse(response);

document.getElementById("btm").innerHTML = json[0].btm;
});

document.getElementById("totalpoints").innerHTML = json[1].totalpoints;
});

document.getElementById("btm").innerHTML = json[1].btm;
});

document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = json[4].average;
});
```

Comment: Why do you so many `});` in your code? Please post a [mcve] which compiles. And please use a code editor which points out all these obvious errors

Comment: Your second, third and fourth "document.getElementById" statements are outside the scope of the callback method for httpGetAsync. The json var is defined inside the scope of the callback method, as such, it can't be reached

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Keep your browser console open so you'll notice them.

Comment: You get `"btm"` twice. The second time is overwriting the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing your callback function with extra "});" after each document.getElementById...

Remove them and your code should work.

```js
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)  {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
     callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
  xmlHttp.send(null);
}

httpGetAsync('https://spreadsheet.glitch.me/?key=1JBbAHH1DFtO1r56lr94lUqd8H7qPcHncJskcPq0r96o', function(response) {
var json = JSON.parse(response);

document.getElementById("btm").innerHTML = json[0].btm;
document.getElementById("totalpoints").innerHTML = json[1].totalpoints;
document.getElementById("btm").innerHTML = json[1].btm;
document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = json[4].average;
});
```

```html
<div id="btm"></div>
<div id="totalpoints"></div>
<div id="average"></div>
```

Comment: Run this code, it says `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"`

Comment: @JeremyThille I copy pasted an extra carridge return character. Fixed that. Thanks